# Could @RequestMapping and struts's mapping be used in the same time?

Tags: spring, annotations, struts

Could I use action mappings in `struts.xml` and Spring's `RequestMapping` annotation in the same time?
(my environment is Struts 2.3.1 and Spring 3.1.1)

in my `struts.xml` something like this:

```
<package name="proj" namespace="/proj" extends="proj-default">
    <action name="home" class="proj">
        <result name="success" type="tiles">proj.home</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

and one of my class is annotated like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/dialog")
public class MyDialogController {
    ...
    @RequestMapping(value="/info", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String info(NativeWebRequest request) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer is YES.
I just need to configure the spring configuration additionally.

First, I add Spring's `DispatcherServlet` in `web.xml`

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>profile</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>profile</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/testProj/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Then add below codes additionally in `applicationContext.xml`

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/>
```

Finally, I create a `profile-servlet.xml` which contains the request mapping setting

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <value>
            /profile/*=profileController
        </value>
    </property>
    <property name="alwaysUseFullPath" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

And it works fine now.